# InterfaceVpcEndpoint vs VpcEndpoint in AWS CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, aws-cdk, vpc-endpoint

AWS CDK provides an [InterfaceVpcEndpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-ec2.InterfaceVpcEndpoint.html) and a [VpcEndpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-ec2.VpcEndpoint.html). What is the difference between these two constructs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its about [CDK constructs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/constructs.html). You should know that there are 3 levels of constructs: L1 (low-level), L2 (regular) and L3 (high-level patterns).

`InterfaceVpcEndpoint` is L2 used to create interface VPC endpoints. `VpcEndpoint` class is a [support class](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-construct-library.html#module-contents) which is parent of `InterfaceVpcEndpoint`. You can think of `VpcEndpoint` as being somewhere between L2 and L1. You shouldn't use, or even cant use it directly, as its used to encapsulate common functionality between Interface VPC endpoints and Gateway VPC endpoints.

So to create interface endpoint, use `InterfaceVpcEndpoint`. Similarly to create gateway endpoint, use `GatewayVpcEndpoint`. Both are L2 constructs.